# Add line to pandas plot

Tags: python, pandas

Using pandas I create a plot of a time series like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

rng = pd.date_range('2016-01-01', periods=60, freq='D')
ts = pd.Series(np.random.randn(len(rng)), index=rng)

ax = ts.plot()
ax.axhline(y=ts.mean(), xmin=-1, xmax=1, color='r', linestyle='--', lw=2)
```

[image]

I would like to add another horizontal line at the level of the mean using only data from February. The mean is just `ts.loc['2016-02']`, but how do I add a horizontal line at that level that doesn't go across the whole figure, but only for the dates in February?

Answer (score 4):

Or you can create a new time series whose values are the mean and index only spans February.

```
ts_feb_mean = ts['2016-02'] * 0 + ts['2016-02'].mean()
```

All together it looks like:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

rng = pd.date_range('2016-01-01', periods=60, freq='D')
ts = pd.Series(np.random.randn(len(rng)), index=rng)

# Feb mean
ts_fm = ts['2016-02'] * 0 + ts['2016-02'].mean()
ts_fm = ts_fm.reindex_like(ts)

# Total mean
ts_mn = ts * 0 + ts.mean()

# better control over ax
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ts.plot(ax=ax)
ts_mn.plot(ax=ax)
ts_fm.plot(ax=ax)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `xmin` and `xmax` to control where in the chart the line starts and ends.  But this is in percent of the chart.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed([3, 1415])
rng = pd.date_range('2016-01-01', periods=60, freq='D')
ts = pd.Series(np.random.randn(len(rng)), index=rng)
ts_feb = ts['2016-02']

# used to figure out where to start and stop
ts_len = float(len(ts))
ts_len_feb = float(len(ts_feb))
ratio = ts_len_feb / ts_len

ax = ts.plot()
ax.axhline(y=ts.mean() * 5, xmin=0, xmax=1, color='r', linestyle='--', lw=2)
ax.axhline(y=ts_feb.mean() * 5, xmin=(1. - ratio), xmax=1, color='g', linestyle=':', lw=2)
```